# SonarQube - Views Portfolio Plugin - Project vs Filter Motion Chart

Tags: plugins, widget, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.1

I completed a POC on View Portfolio plugin using SonarQube (5.1.x)/latest version. Got my trial license for **Views Portfolio plugin** and created few custom VIEWS, Sub-Views and various Measures.

Created custom/shared Dashboards which have various widgets utilizing these views/sub-views / measures that I created above. Everything is working as expected as far as Views Portfolio Plugin or Sonar Qube is concerned.

Though I'm bumped by this one issue which is coming in "**Project Motion Chart**" Widget (we use widgets Dashboards to show meaningful metrics about projects / views (which treats projects as components), see Views Portfolio Management plugin's docs for more info).

**Can you tell why Project Motion chart widget is showing only 1 ball ?**

Another similar widget is: "**Filter Motion Chart**" widget which is working as expected.

See the images to see the current setup / # of projects in the custom View/Sub-View and measure that I have created.

[image]

and when I use Views/Sub-View and Measure in the custom Dashboard I created using Project / Filter motion Chart widgets, I see this:

[image]

Comment: Do you know which project/view is the blue ball in the project motion chart ?

Comment: Yes, ProjectC. Do you think Project Motion Chart will populate if I do a fresh publish of all other project's analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like I needed to run fresh sonarRunner (SonarQube Analysis) for all the concerned projects and now all projects are showing up in Project Filter Motion chart.